# In VC++, how to check if a directory is empty?

Tags: visual-c++

In VC++, how should I check if a directory is empty?
Is there any function? I am a novice here.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use [PathIsDirectoryEmpty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773623%28VS.85%29.aspx) method.

Answer (score 3):

You could use some methods like [FindFirstFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364418%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [FindNextFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364428%28VS.85%29.aspx) to check if there are any files in the directory.

Also see [this](http://www.dotnet42.com/NG_microsoft.public.dotnet.framework/A_40226/ThreadDetail.htm):

> If the directory is empty,
>   FindFirstFile() will only find the
>   entry for the directory itself (".")
>   and FindNextFile() will fail with
>   ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND.